# My cactus has small white bugs in its soil

Tags: bugs, parasites

I watered my cactus today and it had some small white bugs on it. What can I do to stop him from being killed. Please help me fast because my cactus is my best friend and I don’t want him to die.

He also has turned yellowish and squishy.
I water him once a week.
Please help.

[image: This is what it looks like]
[image]

It first looked like fungus then a watered it and after a few minutes I looked at it and there was small wight bugs

Comment: The yellowing and squishy is probably caused by overwatering. Try to water it every 2 weeks or so, be sure the soil dries up between waterings. Use a pot with drainage holes. Please explain more about the bugs, when they live in the soil and jump they are probably harmless (springtails).

Comment: I do wait for the soil to dry. Also they don’t jump instead They burrowed when I found them. They Live in Soil

Comment: Can you explain how the bugs look like, or make a picture? It is hard to help you this way.

Comment: They were there but they are gone now. 
I would say maybe a quarter of a mm They have no wings.

Comment: Wow, that's really small. Do you have proper drainage in your pot?

Comment: Those are probably fungus gnats, attracted by the fungus and moisture, because you have overwatered your cactus. If you have overwatered your cactus,  you might be killing the roots and the plant will die shortly. Learn more about taking care of a cactus before you get one. They do not need water very often.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me as if your soil is unfit for cacti - far too much organic material.
A cactus cannot cope with too many bacteria / fungi / etc, it does better sandy rubble soil with good drainage.